# Move occurs when using a method that requires ownership

Tags: rust, reqwest

I am using Reqwest to call some APIs. I want to have a general function to parse the response as below:

```
async fn response_to_result(response: &Response) -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    let status = response.status().as_u16();
    let response_message = response.text().await?; // Move here because of response.text() 
    return if status == 200 {
        Ok(())
    } else {
        Err(anyhow::anyhow!(response_message))
    };
}
```

This is the error I got:

```
move occurs because `*response` has type `reqwest::Response`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

The move occurs by calling `response.text()` (method definition: `pub async fn text(self) -> crate::Result<String>`). Normally with params we can pass by reference, but with the method I don't have any idea. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: "Does anyone have a solution for this?" check status first ? BTW the return here is useless

Comment: Please include the full error message, which points at the place where the move happens and contains additional context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Normally with params, we can pass with reference

That's true as long as the method doesn't consume the value. `text()` does, since it assembles all the chunks together for you. Here's its signature:

```
pub async fn text(self) -> Result<String>
```

Note the `self` rather than `&self`. After running `text()`, the whole stream is consumed, a String is constructed, and it's returned to you to manage. `Response` does not have an internal buffer that stores all this data. It's gone once the stream is consumed; keeping track of it is the job of the caller. Future calls to `text()` (or `bytes()`) couldn't work. So `text()` destroys the entire `Response`. You can't continue to use it after calling `text()`.

So you'll need to pass the actual value, not a borrow of it. Remove the `&` on `Response`.

If you want a (mutable) borrowing version of this, you'll need to assemble the chunks yourself with `chunk()`. But you probably don't want to do this. You probably just want to pass `Response` (without the `&`) and let `response_to_result()` consume the value like `text()`.